# EmguCV Canny black window

Tags: c#, emgucv, edge-detection

i have another question. Idk what is happening buti tried to make Canny edge detector. Problem is that when i want to detect edges on simple shape like square, the program is able to detect it. But when i want to detect shapes on not very simple image program just gives me image filled by only black color. Do you guys have an idea what is going on?

I use this code below:

```
 public Bitmap CannyEdge(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        Image<Gray, Byte> Cannybmp;
        Image<Gray, Byte> GrayBmp;
        Image<Bgr, Byte> orig = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(bmp);
        Image<Bgr, Byte> imgSmooth;
        Bitmap output;

        imgSmooth = orig.PyrDown().PyrUp();
        imgSmooth._SmoothGaussian(3);
        GrayBmp = imgSmooth.Convert<Gray, byte>();

        Gray grayCannyThreshold = new Gray(160.0);
        Gray grayThreshLinking = new Gray(80.0);

        Cannybmp = GrayBmp.Canny(grayCannyThreshold.Intensity, grayThreshLinking.Intensity);
        output = Cannybmp.ToBitmap();

        //int a = 5;
        return output;

    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        pictureBox2.Image = CannyEdge(bmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to set your grayCannyThreshold to become lesser the value of your grayThreshLinking?

```
Gray grayCannyThreshold = new Gray(80.0);
Gray grayThreshLinking = new Gray(160.0);
```

Comment: yes i tried it... But I found out that EmguCV 3.0 has broken pyrDown() function... so i used only pyrUp() that should be fine for me :)